# How to style li:hover without affecting its parent elements

Tags: css

I am working on styling a sidebar menu with CSS. This menu uses nested `<ul>` and `<li>` elements. The problem is that when sub-menu items are hovered over, their parent elements activate as well.

As I understand it, a style like this `#menu-sidebar-main>li:hover>a` prevents the effect from cascading further than the first `<li><a>` element within the top level `<ul>`, identified as `#menu-sidebar-main`. Is there a similar trick to prevent the lower-level `<li>` elements from cascading upward to the elements above it?

In my examples below you can see that when you hover over a MID LEVEL element, its parent TOP LEVEL element is also highlighted, and when you hover over a BOTTOM LEVEL element, its parent MID LEVEL and TOP LEVEL elements are both highlighted.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Typeless/gmsmj22t/

Code Snippet Below:

```css
/* SIDEBAR MENU */

/* top level */

#menu-sidebar-main {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li {
  background-color: #797979;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-sidebar-main>li:hover,
#menu-sidebar-main>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #791416;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* mid level */

#menu-sidebar-main li ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li {
  background-color: #b3b2b2;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-sidebar-main>li>ul.sub-menu>li:hover,
#menu-sidebar-main>li>ul.sub-menu>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #791416;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* bottom level */

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li ul li {
  background-color: #edebeb;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-sidebar-main>li>ul.sub-menu>li>ul.sub-menu>li:hover,
#menu-sidebar-main>li>ul.sub-menu>li>ul.sub-menu>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #791416;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* current page */

li.current_page_item {
  background-color: #791416 !important;
}

li.current_page_item a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul id="menu-sidebar-main" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-268" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-71 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-268"><a href="#">Top Level Active Page</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-269" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-269"><a href="#">Mid Level</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-270" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-270"><a href="#">Mid Level</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-271"><a href="#">Mid Level</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-272" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-272"><a href="#">Mid Level</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-273" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-273"><a href="#">Bottom Level</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-274" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-274"><a href="#">Bottom Level</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-275"><a href="#">Bottom Level</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You cannot stop css inheriting not matter what selector you use, your css seems to be massive to achieve the output you have currently.

Comment: Thanks for the review. It's a work in progress, that's why I'm here :)

Comment: Here is the simplified example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvrYXr

Comment: Thanks, it looks nice and will make a great reference - but broad selectors are not good in every case - it often affects other elements when you drop them into a fully themed web page with other similarly classed elements. For example `.menu` in my case was also used for the top menu. Not my preference, but I've got to work within the parameters I'm given. That's the primary reason for the super-long-tail selectors I've chosen in my examples.

Comment: Like I said it was only an example I updated it again now it is even simpler, one more advice is don't use ID for styling use class instead, and keep it as short as possible.

Comment: @Stickers Thanks again for that example, I've learned a lot from it and improved my version immensely. I see what you mean, it's not about the selector, but about organizing things more elegantly. Always good to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the changes to the hovered `a` element, not to the hovered `li` element, which includes the submenus:

```
/* SIDEBAR MENU */

/* top level */

#menu-sidebar-main {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li {
  background-color: #797979;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  /* this should be #ffffff but temporarily #000000 to make sure hover on lower items isn't affecting this one */
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


#menu-sidebar-main>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #791416;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* mid level */

#menu-sidebar-main li ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li {
  background-color: #b3b2b2;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#menu-sidebar-main>li>ul.sub-menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #791416;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* bottom level */

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li ul li {
  background-color: #edebeb;
}

#menu-sidebar-main li ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#menu-sidebar-main>li>ul.sub-menu>li>ul.sub-menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #791416;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* current page */

li.current_page_item {
  background-color: #791416 !important;
}

li.current_page_item a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

**UPDATE:** added `display: block` to `a` elements to achieve requested effect.

Comment: Thanks Miguel - With this solution is there any way to get the hover over color to extend to cover the whole width of the menu and not just the link text?

Comment: Sure, check the updated code (just had to add one line).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Just FYI, in your code there was one tiny typo: `#menu-sidebar-main>li:hover>a` should be `#menu-sidebar-main>li>a:hover` - after I fixed that, all was good.